# Emulating mobile/desktop/ipad on a div element doesn't work

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a `<div>` in my admin page, and I want to present the user how the `<div>` will look like in desktop / mobile / iPad etc ...

## Problem

The `<div>` doesn't make the col-md-4 collapse on each other when changing the div's width & height, instead the columns are shrinking but stay on the same row.

If I manually change the browser's width - they do collapse on top of each other.
This is because the viewport - is actually changing, vs when the browser is on full screen, and I just shrink the div's width manually.

How can I make it work then ?

### Edit - adding an example in CodePen

When trying out the example, see the difference between clicking on the icon vs shrinking the browser itself

- Shrinking the div, the col-md-4 just makes the width of each col smaller
- vs. changing the browser window with the mouse which makes the blocks collapse on top of each other
- It works OK on real devices, again I just want to emulate it in the `<div>`

html ( Bootstrap & jQuery )

```
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h3 class="text-center screen_change">
    <div>
        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-3x fa-tablet"         onclick="activate_device('tablet');"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-3x fa-desktop active" onclick="activate_device('desktop');"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-fw fa-3x fa-mobile"         onclick="activate_device('mobile');"></i>
    </div>     
  </h3>

  <div class="row grid_to_change">

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">A</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">B</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">C</button>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

CSS ( LESS )

```
.screen_change {
  .fa {
    cursor: pointer;

    &.active {
      border-bottom: #236B90 5px solid;
    }
  }
}

.grid_to_change {
  border: #444 2px solid;
}
```

JS ( Bootstrap & jQuery )

```
var SCREEN_SIZES = [
    { device: 'tablet',  width: '1024',   height: '768'  },
    { device: 'desktop', width: "100%",   height: "auto" },
    { device: 'mobile',  width: '480',    height: '800'  } 
];

function WxH(args) {
        // Change Width x Height
        // args = { width: X, height: Y }

        $('.grid_to_change').animate({ 
          width: args.width, 
          height: args.height 
        }, 500, function() {
            if ( args.height == "auto" )
                $(this).removeAttr('style');
        });        
    }


function activate_device (which_device) {

   // Seek fot the supported device
        var which_device = SCREEN_SIZES.filter(function(x){  return x.device == which_device; })[0];

        if ( ! which_device ) {
            console.error("Unable to find a support device: ", which_device);
            return;
        }       

        // - Make all other devices non-active
        $('.screen_change .fa').removeClass("active");

        // - Activate the chosen device's CSS
        $('.screen_change .fa-' + which_device.device).addClass("active");

        // - Change the display dimensions to the one requested
        WxH(which_device);
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bwAzLw

Any ideas ?

Comment: Chrome has a tool to test the resolutions.

Comment: Show us what you have tried. If you are using bootstrap you should not have any issues unless the mark-up is not right.

Comment: You wanted a CodePen example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bwAzLw there's a codepen example ...

Comment: @DominiqueLorre yes I know, but as I said, when the actual resolution change - it works, but when you change the `<div>` to the width/height - it's not responsive

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the meta viewport tag without effecting the whole page.

You could write some code which takes the CSS file you want to display, read through it removing anything but the parts you want (eg, mobile dimensions) and use that modified version with the page loaded in a div.

Comment: mmm but the div is already there ... and the switch is done on the fly where the user see how the elements are being re-positioned ..